# Videos not playing in safari when using html5 video tag

Tags: python, django, html, heroku, safari

I am building a website using django. I am trying to include a video in my webpage using html5  tag.  My code is given below.

```
<video controls style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" id="video" preload="none">
                    <source src="{% static 'media/video1.ogv' %}" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'/>
                    <source src="{% static 'media/video1.webm' %}" type='video/webm'>
                    <source src="{% static 'media/video1.mp4' %}" type='video/mp4'>
                    <p>Video is not visible, most likely your browser does not support HTML5 video</p>
                </video>
```

But video is not playing in the safari browser. I changed the video to video1.mov file, but still is not playing. I am using heroku for deployment. I checked if Quickstart is installed. It is installed already. 
The error shown is

```
Failed to load resource: Plug-in handled load
http://www.***.com/static/media/video1.mov
```

Can some one help me to sort this out?

Comment: does Safari support this video format?

Comment: it supports mp4 formats

Comment: Safari used to have a bug that would freeze playback if the first source tag wasn't playable (i.e. not mp4).  I'm not sure if this bug is still present, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could be an issue with how the MP4 is encoded. I know the question is a little old, but I had the same issue, so in case helps you or somebody else that finds this first like I did:

It seems that QuickTime (which is the plugin that plays MP4s for Safari) only works when the file is encoded with a certain profile. This is specified in question #2 in [Apple's FAQ](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/FrequentlyAskedQuestions/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH103-SW1).

> Although the protocol specification does not limit the video and audio formats, the current Apple implementation supports the following formats:
>
> Video:
>   H.264 Baseline Level 3.0, Baseline Level 3.1, Main Level 3.1, and High Profile Level 4.1.
>
> Audio:
>   HE-AAC or AAC-LC up to 48 kHz, stereo audio
>   MP3 (MPEG-1 Audio Layer 3) 8 kHz to 48 kHz, stereo audio
>   AC-3 (for Apple TV, in pass-through mode only)

You'll need to encode using one of those video profiles to get it to work with QuickTime, and hence Safari.

If you're targeting iOS devices also, [this table](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH102-SW8) might be helpful too, in order to know what you're compatible with:

> **Baseline 3.0:** All devices
>
> **Baseline 3.1:** iPhone 3G and later, and iPod touch 2nd generation and later.
>
> **Main profile 3.1:** iPad (all versions), Apple TV 2 and later, and iPhone 4 and later.
>
> **Main Profile 4.0:** Apple TV 3 and later, iPad 2 and later, and iPhone 4S and later
>
> **High Profile 4.0:** Apple TV 3 and later, iPad 2 and later, and iPhone 4S and later.
>
> **High Profile 4.1:** iPad 2 and later and iPhone 4S and later.

And finally, here are the `ffmpeg` options for creating these encodings:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#AdditionalInformationTips

It's also useful to know that you can just open a file in QuickTime (you don't have to load through Safari) in order to check whether a file works.

Comment: I opened an mp4 in Quicktime@10.4 and exported for iPhone (.m4v) and it still doesn't work on iPhone. Wtf???